# how to add hundredth of second in datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

(newcomer..., working with Jupyter Notebook)

I have some data from an instrument where the date and time comes in 7 separated variables (SerYear, SerMon, SerDay, SerHour, SerMin, SerSec, SerHund, all integers). The 'Ser' for 'Series', and Hund is hundredth of second

I using the follow code to 'assemble' the date time (year, month and day are constants and without the SerHund, np = numpy). It works (Could it be done in a better way?)

```
time_adcp=[]

for i in range(len(SerHour)):
    c_time = datetime.datetime(Year,Month,Day,SerHour[i],SerMin[i],SerSec[i])
    time_adcp = np.append(time_adcp,c_time)
```

Just including the SerHund as the next variable, it is understood as 'microsecond'. The first value of SerHund is 61, so the results that comes is

```
time_adcp=[]

for i in range(len(SerHour)):
    c_time = datetime.datetime(Year,Month,Day,SerHour[i],SerMin[i],SerSec[i],SerHund[i])
    time_adcp = np.append(time_adcp,c_time)

print(SerSec[0],SerHund[0],time_adcp[0])  # to check out...`
```

[29] [61] 2019-02-06 09:35:29.000061

So... I thought if I multiply the SerHund by 10,000 I would get the right values (29.61 seconds), however, what I get is

[29] [61] 2019-02-06 09:35:29.020176

My 1st question is: how do I add the hundredth of second in the datetime?

and the 2nd: Why multiplying by 10e4 doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`10e4` is too much ... and a `float`:

```
print(1e4)  # 10000.0
print(10e4) # 100000.0
```

Your code works if you use `*10000` (or `int( ... *1e4)` (to circumvent `1e4` being a `float`):

```
Year,Month,Day,SerHour,SerMin,SerSec,SerHund=2019,2,6,9,35,29,61

import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(Year,Month,Day,SerHour,SerMin,SerSec,SerHund)
print(dt)
dt = datetime.datetime(Year,Month,Day,SerHour,SerMin,SerSec,SerHund*10000)
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
2019-02-06 09:35:29.000061
2019-02-06 09:35:29.610000
```

You can use `1e4` if you `int(...)` it:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(Year,Month,Day,SerHour,SerMin,SerSec,int(SerHund*1e4))
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
2019-02-06 09:35:29.610000
```

Comment: Thanks. Multiplying the hundredth of seconds by 10000 works when it is outside the loop. When I run it in the loop, the results are the the same I showed (2019-02-06 09:35:29.020176)...

Comment: @Car Check your data then - if this does not work with the data you have got, then your "hundreth of a seconds" (wich is odd) are probably milliseconds (1/1000) which would make much more sense overall. If there is any  SerHund in your data  that is more then 99 then you are probably handling milliseconds and need to use 1e3 (1000) to multiply them by - in that case values up to 999 would be ok to be had as milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

This gives you how to get part of a second.

```
import datetime
from time import strftime
n = datetime.datetime.now()
m = float(n.strftime("%S.%f"))
o = int(m)
p= m-o
q=round(p*100)/100
print(n,q)
```

This gives you how to do the add part - the easiest bit:

```
from datetime import timedelta
d = timedelta(microseconds=10) #(1000ms = 1 sec => 1/100th sec = 10ms)
d2 = n + d
print(d2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have the time in separated variables. My problem is to put all together, including the 'hundredth of seconds'. As Patrick showed above, however it doesn't work inside the loop.

Comment: Then the heading of your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, rather a solution for my problem. Must use `int()` for the variable which contain the 'hundredth of second', otherwise, it gives me the wrong result.

```
time_adcp=[]

for i in range(len(SerHour)):
    c_time = datetime.datetime(Year[i],Month[i],Day[i],Hour[i],Min[i],Sec[i],int(Hund[i])*10000)
    time_adcp = np.append(time_adcp,c_time)
```

However, I don't understand why I don't need use the `int()` for the other variables which came from the same file...??? And, more important, what's that wrong result?

From the beginning:

1) I loaded a structure '.mat'  file, which was originally exported by other than Matlab. I used

```
import scipy.io as sio

d_adcp = sio.loadmat('file_adcp.mat')
```

I separated the date&time variables from `d_adcp`

```
Year = d_adcp['SerYear']
Month = d_adcp['SerMon']
Day = d_adcp['SerDay']
Hour = d_adcp['SerHour']
Min = d_adcp['SerMin']
Sec = d_adcp['SerSec']
Hund = d_adcp['SerHund']
```

Now, what sort of variables are these? They looks like integers

```
print(Year[0],Month[0],Day[0],Hour[0],Min[0],Sec[0],Hund[0])
[19] [2] [6] [9] [35] [29] [61]
```

verifying, they are no integers

```
isinstance(Year,int)
False
```

neither float!?

```
isinstance(Year,float)
False
```

As far as I know, `datetime` only accept integers. So, why did it work at first, even giving me wrong result? And why I need use `int()` only for `Hund`

I would appreciate very much some help to understand what's going on... thanks.